# What is the fastest way from Zurich to Eindhoven, by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, switzerland, netherlands, zurich, eindhoven

I'm looking for the fastest way using the normal public transport options (plane, train, etc.) from Zurich to Eindhoven in Autumn. Flying seems not really to be a option since there seem to be no flights from Switzerland to Eindhoven. The trains that I could find take around 12 hours or even longer and require to change trains a couple of times. The best option I could find so far is flying to Amsterdam and taking a train to Eindhoven, but is there any other option I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. The option you mention is by far the fastest. Fly directly from Zurich to Amsterdam. Swiss has four flights per day. This takes 1h30. Then take a [train](http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/home) from the [Schiphol airport](http://www.schiphol.nl/index_en.html) to Eindhoven. That's another 1h30. There are plenty of (direct) trains between Schiphol and Eindhoven. Add the time in between to get luggage, go to the train etc. And you are done.

If you comply to traffic regulations, you won't be faster by car (taxi or rental car) on the Schiphol-Eindhoven leg.

There are also direct flights from Brussels to Zurich. Brussels Airport is a 1h30 drive (by car) from Eindhoven. The train takes at least 2h45 and you have to change 2 or 3 times. Cologne and Düsseldorf are even further apart. Maastricht, Rotterdam and Antwerp do not have direct flights to Zurich.

And this brings us back to Amsterdam ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of personal preference, of course, but I'd probably take the train. First airplane and then train sounds like a lot of hassle (check-in, check-out, transport, etc.). Also, you could get into trouble if the airplane is delayed and you miss the train you have booked.

On September 12th, for example, there are various eight hour train connections, but then one has to change at least three times, which can be risky.

However, on [bahn.de](http://bahn.hafas.de) (screen shot in German), I found one connection where you only have to *change twice*. Granted, it takes ten hours, but trains should be comfortable (ICE) and you have one and a half hours to kill in Frankfurt, not the worst place.

Don't forget to check other days. September 12th was just a random example of a day in autumn.

[image: just two changes]

Comment: There is no need to book train tickets in adavance in the Netherlands. On the vast majority of the trains it is even not possible t book in adavnce. Just go to the station, buy a ticket and take the next train.

Comment: Regarding the train connection you propose: only 8 minutes in Utrect. That's a very tight connection an you might miss it

Comment: And ICEs are not always comfortable, a lot of them are quite fault-prone :)

Comment: Indeed, 8 minutes is not much to change. On the other hand, the train ticket from Zürich to Eindhoven guarantees that you will get to your destination. So if you miss IC861 due to a delay of ICE124, then you can just take the next train without surcharge. In Germany, because of a train delay, Deutsche Bahn once even paid me a taxi ride from Karlsruhe to Strasbourg (more than 80 km).

Comment: Anyway, the connection from Utrecht to Eindhoven is not the bottleneck, unless you arrive at asocial hours. During the day there are at least 2 to 3 trains per hours on this route.

Comment: With a normal train ticket you don't have to worry about what trains you take, as long as you stay on the route. Such a ticket is valid on any service along it's route. If you have a saver ticket you must normally take the trains printed on your ticket, but if you miss a connection because one train was late you can still just take the next one. Don't worry about 8 minute connections. These are quite normal.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException as André correctly points out there is no need for train reservations at all in NL. If you miss your train, take the next one about 15 minutes later. I can recommend http://grouptickets.nl for a ticket. Those are tickets that 7 people with the same _destination_ can share. Those only have a date and destination on them. Those are valid on all trains operated by NS. Plan your route on ns.nl or 9292.nl.

Answer (score 5):

One train option that can be quite economical, and save you some time is to take the night train. There is a daily night train from Zürich to Amsterdam. Take that train as far as Utrecht, and take an IC to Eindhoven from there. The ["CityNightline"](http://www.citynightline.de/citynightline/view/en/index.shtml) night train has very good deals if you buy sufficiently in advance. 
You leave Zürich in the evening, and you're in Eindhoven the next day in the morning.

Comment: Night trains are phased out, so do check whether they are still available when you need them. Alas, as it was always a nice option for long distance travel.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Zurich/Eindhoven) going through Amsterdam or Dusseldorf are your two quickest options.

NB: pedantic sidenote: There is also this option of going from [Zurich (the Netherlands)](https://maps.google.be/maps?q=zurich%20netherlands&ie=UTF8&client=safari&oe=UTF-8&hnear=Zurich,%20S%C3%BAdwest%20Frysl%C3%A2n,%20Friesland,%20Nederland&t=m&z=14) to Eindhoven which would take you [3.5 hours](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Zurich-Netherlands/Eindhoven) by public transport.